# Is EM radiation released when metals, that have free electrons, are accelerated?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, conductors

I have read that charged particles, when accelerated, emit Electromagnetic Radiation. This was the basis for rejection of the Rutherford's atomic model. But is this statement complete?
Metals have free electrons, which are charged particles. So, when a metal body is under acceleration, why isn't even some EM radiation produced at a microscopic level even if the metal body as a whole is neutral?

Comment: Is the metal uncharged perhaps?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, the metal body as a whole is uncharged. But at the microscopic level, won't there be any EM radiation at all?

Comment: since any Atom or molecule in the air is constantly moving and accelerating you should have EM waves plenty. but the Atoms are neutral, so there is no netto charge moving.